# Remove type-information from JSON result

Tags: json, jersey, jax-rs

Currently I am trying to create a webservice which simply returns a list;

```
@Path("/random")
@Singleton
public class Random
{
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MyResult<String> test()
    {
        MyResult<String> test =  new MyResult<String>();
        test.add("Awesome");

        return test;
    }
}
```

And my MyResult class looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyResult<T> implements Iterable<T>
{
    private ArrayList<T> _items;
    private int _total;

    public MyResult()
    {
        _items = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getItems()
    {
        return _items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<T> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public int getTotal()
    {
        return _total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total)
    {
        _total = total;
    }

    public void add(T item)
    {
        getItems().add(item);
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return getItems().iterator();
    }
}
```

Now I get the following result from the service:

```
{"items":[{"@type":"xs:string","$":"Awesome"}],"total":"0"}
```

But I don't want any of this information, I just require this:

```
{"items":["Awesome"],"total":"0"}
```

It seems to me this requires some configuration somewhere, who know how to get the required result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using jackson, take a look at [@JsonTypeInfo](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html) annotation. It is used for configuring details of if and how type information is used with JSON serialization and deserialization. The use and behaviour of it would depend on the version of jackson you are using.

Comment: @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NONE ) was the solution

Answer (score 1):

To completely suppress type information, I had to use the following annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
@JsonDeserialize(as=NoType.class)
```